# Reading files with Intellij idea IDE

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, ide

I am a long time eclipse user and I have started to play around with IntelliJ IDEA.

So from my understanding, a project in IntelliJ is the same as the Eclipse workspace. Additionally, a module in IntelliJ is the equivalent of a project in Eclipse.

I created a project in IntelliJ, but I’m still not sure why there is a `src` folder in it if it is supposed to be a workspace.

Afterwards, I created a module in the project and a class inside the `src` directory of the new module with this code:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File ("test123.txt"));
        String answer = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println(answer);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get an error trying to read the file. I tried putting the .txt file inside my src file which is located inside the module and outside the `src` directory but inside the module. But in both cases the file is not found. Yes the code works, I tried it on Eclipse and it works fine. The file name is spelled correctly as well.

Here is a picture of my project/workspace if it is helpful:

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ]

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just move the file directly to the project folder which calls *Java* (and something under the blue-blurred stripe you made :P).

If that doesn't help, then move the `test123.txt` file to `FirstJavaProgram` directory.

You can also change filename to one of these:

1. `src/test123.txt`
2. `FirstJavaProgram/src/test123.txt`

I am not sure which one will be fine in your case.

Comment: I moved it to the Java project folder and that did the trick. But why does it work there? Shouldn't the project folder be like a "Workspace". If I want to create multiple programs to do different tasks they should be different modules inside the Java project, correct? Won't the text files get mixed up? Isn't the point of a project to hold multiple modules that do different unrelated tasks?

Comment: I know that usually huge projects are divided to smaller modules, but then Maven is the main used tool. I have never taken part in such a big project because for now I am just an amateur :P You are right. However, I would suggest you to take up Maven and start to use it, it is amazingly useful and can help you with file storing

Comment: I feel that you have been using Eclipse or NetBeans. IntelliJ IDEA is quite different in project approach. In eclipse/netbeans there were left-panel in which all your projects were shown. IntelliJ doesn't have feature like this. You open just **ONE** project per one IntelliJ IDEA application/window. Naturally, you can open multiple projects by: File->Reopen project->choose_some_project-> press Open in new window

Comment: Okay so a project in intelliJ is not the same as the workspace in Eclipse. I really hate the idea that I can't have all my separate projects in the left panel. Thanks for helping understand the IDE!

Comment: yup, at first is could make some problems, but I assure you that IntelliJ is the best Java IDE and you will become accustomed with it. Showing multiple projects-feature is nothing, comparing to its possibilities :) you will find

Comment: Thanks man, it helped my question too :P

Comment: Please provide an example. It might be simple for you but not for others.

Answer (score 26):

Use the full path of the file instead.

Right click on your file in your project, select "Copy Path", and paste that in to the path of your file.

EDIT:  You could also use a relative path for your file.  If your file is located in `resources/`, then you could use the form `./resources/yourfile.txt`.

```
├── resources
│   └── test123.txt
└── src
    ├── MainClass.java
```

Comment: That did do the trick. But it won't work if I move the module to another location or send it to another person.

Comment: At that point, consider allowing the end user to provide the path themselves in the running of the program.  Hard coding the path is usually a last-ditch effort.

Comment: Is there no alternative like in Eclipse where the file can get stored outside of the src folder and I could simply call it just by its name? Without having to give a path and not having to put outside of the Module

Comment: I have this problem too. Did you find a good solution to this?

Answer (score 15):

Yesterday I met the same trouble as you.

change the setting of IDEA.
run->Edit Configurations -> 
(select your Application at left window.then set the input content named "Working directory" at right window)

[image: click here to see the image]

Answer (score 6):

create directory "files" make all files inside this directory.
Select the directory and click right select -> Mark Directory As -> Resources Root :)

Answer (score 5):

**Instructions**

1. Simply right-click on your project directory (the very top folder), 
   then select "New > Directory". Specify a name such as "resources".

[image]

1. (optional) Once the folder is generated then right-click "resources" directory, then select "New > Directory" and create an "images" directory.
2. Drag-and-drop your image file into the "images" or "resources"
   folder you just created.
   Reference your newly added project file with code `File myFile = new File("./resources/images/newfile.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

1. `Run` > `Edit Configurations`
2. Under `Configuration` tab

   - `Working directory`: Your file path is relative to this.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 2):

```
u need to specify complete path inside quotes something like this-->

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("E:\\coding\\ProcessingFiles\\src\\myfile.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine()){
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        input.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort but please make sure how much value your answer adding additionally then earlier answers.