# Java Noob : Dealing with image files in IntelliJ

Tags: java, image, macos, intellij-idea

I am Java NOOB (seriously, about two weeks) and using IntelliJ.

My homework is to make a classes, which can process given images(which is in "input" folder), and store them into the "output" folder.

I really have no idea where to put those two folders(input, output) in.

My question is, which place should I put them in, without changing given directory written in template code.

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvH5P.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, IntelliJ reads files from the top level directory of your project. For you, that is `HW6`. Place the `input` folder there.

See also [Reading files with Intellij idea IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949985/reading-files-with-intellij-idea-ide).

In addition, it is possible to specify the "working directory in IntelliJ". You can specify where files are loaded from from the Run Configurations:
[image: Run Configurations]

Comment: Thank you very much. I solved it with your help and changing \ to //.

Comment: Glad I could help!