# IntellJ IDEA --> The System Can Not Find The Path

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm quiet new on IntelliJ IDEA. Before I used Eclipse IDE so I decided to import some of Eclipse projects in IntelliJ to test it, but I came across a very uncommon problem.

The problem is that I can not give correct relative path for new File. 
I always get following error:

> "java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified"

Code sample:

```
fullPath = "./Project/data/test";
filePath = "./data/";
fileName = "test";
File file = new File(filePath + fileName);  //ERROR LINE
```

I also tried:

```
filePath = "data/test";
filePath = "./Project/data/test";
filePath = "./data/test";
filePath = "Project/data/test";
```

I do not know why is this happening as the same code worked just perfectly in Eclipse. In Eclipse I used "data/test", as it detected relative path directly from project folder.

I found very interesting that full path (from in my case partition E:) is working without problems.

I would appreciate any advice.

Thanks :)

Comment: Doesn't IntellJ allow adjusting the working directory when it runs? I would suggest adding output to find out the current directory to know where it is currently running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading files with Intellij idea IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949985/reading-files-with-intellij-idea-ide)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

put your files and data under **resources** folder and add it to your project artifact from project settings.