# Loading json files

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea, gson

I am developing a Java project using IntelliJ and Maven, but I'm having troubles loading and parsing Json files into it. I am using Gson for the parsing.

This is the snippet of code that causes problems:

```
 public void parseSomething() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    //The Json file contains an array of objects, and I need to put it into a Vector
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>(){}.getType(); 
    List<MyClass> something = new Vector<>();
    try(Reader file = new FileReader("dir/myFile.json")){
        something = gson.fromJson(file, listType);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.something = something; //this sets the attribute of the class
}
```

I am using this method to debug it:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.parseSomething();
    String debug = something.toString(); //I've already implemented a custom toString
    System.out.println(debug);
}
```

A `FileNotFoundException` gets thrown at `try(Reader file = new FileReader("dir/myFile.json"))`.

If my guess is correct, the program doesn't even get to the parsing, because it can't find the file.

## Things I tried:

1. Using absolute path (and slight variations of the relative one, such as `src/main/resources/dir/myFile.json` and `resources/dir/myFile.json`...).
2. Setting the Resource root from both intelliJ and Maven.
3. Using other ways to read a file such as:

   - ClassLoader
     `String fileName = "dir/myFile.json";
     ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
     File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());`
   - InputStreamReader (I get a `NullPointerException` in this way)
     `try(Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(myClass.class.getResourceAsStream("dir/myFile.json"))){...}`

Have you got any idea why the file cannot be found? Are there other ways through which I can load it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in the case of InteliJ, the Reader starts looking for files at the root of the project, so something like this: 
`./path/to/file/dir/MyFile.json`.
The `./` makes it so that it starts to look at the root folder of your project. at `/IdeaProjects/MyProject`, it will in this case start at the `MyProject` folder.

[Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949985/reading-files-with-intellij-idea-ide)

Comment: I think you got it right, because now I get a `NullPointerException` relative to the wrong way I parse the file I guess (when I parse a json array into a vector, do the objects contained in the vector get initialized?). But why can't I use the relative path to the resource folder, if I have set it in intelliJ and Maven?

Comment: @Korax, To be honest, i wouldn't know. But i can offer my 2 cents if you are interested.
You seem to set `something` equal to a new Vector, but you declare it as a List<MyClass>. The outcome of this object would never be a vector, right?

Comment: @Korax   
>Why can't I use the relative path to the resource folder.
You're not the only one, also one of my regular problems. I used to use some form of Library that would store the resources for me in the resources folder. Because i was never able to acces it myself.

Comment: Even declaring `something` as a Vector<MyClass> gives a `NullPointerException` unfortunately.

Comment: @Korax, might this be because an exception is thrown in the try catch block? So `this.something1 = something2` doesnt work, because `something2` was never initialized, and therefore calling `toString` gives a `NullPointer`?

Comment: I think that's not the case because, in the stack trace, the toString method that throws the `NullPointerException` is `MyClass`' one. The toString method mentioned in the code snippet belongs to a class which is an aggregation of MyClass. To be more specific, I have a `Deck` class, which is an aggregation (implemented as a `Vector`) of `Card`: `card.toString()` throws `NullPointerException`.