# How to fix FileNotFoundException caused by class path resource [config.xml] not being found in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to learn spring but getting these exceptions

> -Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [config.xml]
>
> -Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

My Main code:

```
package org.example;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ApplicationContext context = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");
        Student s1= (Student) context.getBean("student1");
        System.out.println(s1);
    }
}
```

Here is my project folder
[My work space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvJGs.png)

I also tried to put my config.xml file outside src in project folder like below but did not work.
[config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgJdG.png)

Comment: It is probably a path problem. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949985/reading-files-with-intellij-idea-ide) can help you

Comment: You appear to be using Maven. The `resources` directory should be a subdirectory of `main` not of `java`. See [Introduction to the Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).